# pass static or dinamic array to same function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic, static

I have this function

```
void myFunction(double** myArray)
```

if `myArray` is definded as dynamic array no problem but if `myArray` is defined as static array
`double myArray[10][3];`
is it still possible to pass the array to the function?

I don't want to have a second function for static array input
`myFunction2(double myArray[][3])`

I would like to have just one function (without its overloaded function) that can have static or dynamic array input.

Comment: *if myArray is definded as dynamic array no problem* -- First, there is a problem, since you did not pass the number of rows or the number of columns.  How is `myFunction` supposed to know the extents of the `double**`, since a `double**` is only a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.  Either work with `double**` entirely, or `double [10][3]` entirely.

Comment: dynamic arrays are usually spelled `std::vector` and those with fixed size `std::array`, then you could use iterators to make the function agnostic of container type

Comment: Advice -- Add a level of abstraction to the code.  Instead of `void myFunction(double** myArray)`, it could be `void myFunction(Array2DClass& myArray)` or similar.  Then `Array2DClass` is one that handles the `double**`, and the user doesn't care what is going on inside of `Array2DClass` to handle those details.  That is the better way to achieve only having to have one `myFunction` implementation.

Comment: You may want to go with a template here... `template<class T> concept DoubleCollection2d = requires(T collection, size_t index) { { collection[index][index] } -> std::same_as<double&> }; template<DoubleCollection2d  T> void myFunction(T&& myArray) { ... }` This works many types: `double**`, `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, `std::map<size_t, std::map<size_t, double>>`, `double[10][3]`...

Comment: If your dynamic array and your static array are both `int[10][3]` you cannot pass **either one of them** to a function that takes `int**`. If you have code that accepts one of those you need to show it.

Comment: The basic issue here is that the **name** of an array decays (in most contexts) into a pointer to its first element. So with `int x[10]` you can write a function `void f(int*)` and call it with `f(x)`. But that's it; an array does not magically turn into a pointer, and a two-dimensional array of `int` is not and never will be a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "C" style arrays and use std::vector/std::array.

In C++ 20 you can use concepts to create a function that accepts any type that has a begin() and end() method like this (and with C++17 it can be done with meta template programming too).

```
#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// In C++ 20 you can use concepts like
// checking if a type has a begin and end method
template<typename container_t>
concept has_begin_end = requires(container_t container)
{
    container.begin();
    container.end();
};

// then make a function (template) using that concept
auto print(const has_begin_end auto& container)
{
    bool comma = false;
    for (const auto& value : container)
    {
        if (comma) std::cout << ",";
        std::cout << value;
        comma = true;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::array<int, 3> array{ 6,7,8 };

    print(vector);
    print(array);

    return 0;
}
```